# Type narrowing by a generic function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, python-typing, type-narrowing

I need to narrow type of a class attribute. It is typed as `MyType | None` and it is expected not be `None` in a specific part of the code. I am using this attribute in a generator expression so I cannot directly use a condition with `raise` or `assert` to narrow it.

Is the code below the correct way to define a generic type-narrowing function? I.e. define argument as a generic type in union with `None` but the return type just as the generic type.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

ValueT = TypeVar('ValueT')

def fail_if_none(value: ValueT | None) -> ValueT:
    """Raises an exception if the value is None.

    Args:
        value: The value to check.

    Raises:
        ValueError: If the value is None.

    Returns:
        The value, guaranteed to not be None.
    """
    if value is None:
        raise ValueError("Value cannot be None.")
    return value
```

Does the code guarantee that the return type `ValueT` will always be seen as not including `None`? Is not there a better way?

---

Here is an example showing how to use the type-narrowing function:

```py
def takes_int(value: int) -> int:
    """Take an int and return it."""
    return value

sequence: list[int | None] = [1, 2, 3, 4, None, 5]

values1 = (takes_int(value) for value in sequence)
# error: Argument 1 to "takes_int" has incompatible type "int | None";
# expected "int"  [arg-type]

values2 = (takes_int(fail_if_none(value)) for value in sequence)
# OK, no type-checker errors
```

I have tested the code with mypy and Pyright. In both type-checkers it seems to work the way I wanted.

Comment: Yes, this looks as a correct and idiomatic way to do this to me. What's exactly you question? If a thing works and typechecks, you probably do not have a StackOverflow question - consider asking on Code Review SE instead.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike The question is if this is the correct way to do it. If it works in this specific case it does not mean that it is correct. Originally I did not think at all that extending `ValueT` of the argument by `| None` can work.

Comment: Just fyi, you _can_ use conditions in generator expressions. The following would pass type safety checks too, though it is not equivalent of course since the `None` values would simply be omitted: `(takes_int(value) for value in sequence if value is not None)`

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg thanks. I know about that. I just prefer to make the program safer by not silently skipping unexpected values.